# using viewtype , onBindViewHolder and onCreateViewHolder are different

Tags: android

I'm studying using viewtype in recyclerview.
I use two viewtypes. when I tested for changing viewtype, there is no change.
I inserted viewtype1 but the result is returned to viewtype0.
the log is like below `D/TAG: ProfileViewHolder onCreateViewHolder
D/TAG: ItemViewHolder onBindViewHolder`
onCreateViewHolder is right, but the ItemViewHolder is not right. each other different.
what should I fix? here is my code.

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(private val context: Context, private val items : ArrayList<DetailModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        if(holder is ProfileViewHolder) {
            holder.name.text = items[position].login
            Glide.with(context)
                .load(items[position].profileImage)
                .centerCrop()
                .override(200,200)
                .error(R.drawable.image_not_found)
                .into(holder.profileImage)
            Log.d("TAG","ProfileViewHolder onBindViewHolder")
        }else if(holder is ItemViewHolder){
            holder.name.text = items[position].name
            holder.description.text = items[position].description
            holder.stargazersCount.text = items[position].stargazersCount.toString()
            Log.d("TAG","ItemViewHolder onBindViewHolder")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        if(viewType == 0) {
            val inflatedView: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.detail_item, parent, false)
            Log.d("TAG","ProfileViewHolder onCreateViewHolder")
            return ItemViewHolder(inflatedView)
        }
        else  {
            val inflatedView: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.profile_item, parent, false)
            Log.d("TAG","ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder")
            return ProfileViewHolder(inflatedView)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount()=items.size

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {

        return items.get(position).id.toLong()
    }

    class ItemViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {


        val name :TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name)
        val description : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description)
        val stargazersCount :TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stargazersCount)

    }

    class ProfileViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        val name :TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.login)
        val profileImage : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileImage)

    }



}
```

```
OnCreate

   var detail = DetailModel()
                detail.login= userId
                detail.viewType=1
                itemList.add(detail)

 setAdapter()
```

Comment: i dont see anything that you say to adapter your view type is? override this   **@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // condition to get view type
    }**

Comment: is this work :/

Answer (score 2):

`viewType` in `onCreateViewHolder` is returned by `RecyclerView.Adapter`, To assign viewType to this adapter for each position, you need to override `getItemViewType`.

In your case it might be like this.

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val detail = items[position]
    return detail.viewType
}
```